# How to sync time between two devices (<30m apart) with a sub milisecond accuracy? (think PTP)

Tags: hardware, time

So my task is to detect the source of banging in a metal tube (picture radiator pipe). The idea is to put two mics to the ends of the tube and measure time differences when they hear banging. The tube is about 30 meters long and I need accuracy of about 50cm, which reflects to about 0.1ms.

I suppose that for that accuracy I need to use PTP, unfortunately, raspberry pi doesn't seem to have native support. Any suggestions how I could pull off this task?

Comment: Hi! As currently phrased, your question is a hardware recommendation question – and these are explicitly off-topic here. However, I think it's easy to rephrase: You don't actually care to know what components to buy, right, you need to solve the *problem* of not having the same time at both ends of the pipe. So, why don't you just ask about how to achieve that?

Comment: Much better, thanks! Now the question is, however, why LAN? Wouldn't a simple cable on a GPIO, maybe with a differential line driver be an easier solution? Or simply use only one PI and connect both microphones to that?

Comment: Also, if you give at least one of the ends a speaker additionally to the microphone, you'd have calibration for free and wouldn't need any time coordination!

Comment: Wow, never thought of that, Sir!!! How about the speed at which the rpi is able to process sound frames? Should Linux be good enough, or do I need a realtime system?

Comment: the speed at which are processed doesn't matter at all. All that matters is that it can record them quickly enough; processing can take place at any time :) But yes, audio rate processing belongs in the category of "ridiculously easy" with the complexity of algorithms you're going to employ.

Comment: how about the loss of signal over long cable? Would I need an amplifier ? If so, does it introduce some further delay?

Comment: order of magnitude of electrical signals travelling is 2 to 3 · 10⁸ m/s. That's 100000 times faster than sound in air, i.e. the delay won't matter. Can't tell you how you plan to use which microphones, so, can't help you. But again, delay does not matter at all if it's the same for both.

Comment: I see. I was more worried about the potential amplifier in the cable - that causes some delay, doesn't it?

Comment: please read my comment in full: delay doesn't matter, as long as it's the same for both microphones. So use one amplifier for each, and you're good. Also, nah, the delay of an amplifier should be negligible.